# Storing '\n' character from cin

Tags: c++

I need to get input from the user and store it as a character. The issue is including escape sequences.

Here's an example:

```
string userInput;
char delimiter;

cout << "Enter Delimiter: ";
cin >> userInput;

if(userInput == "\n"){
    delimiter = '\n';
}
else{
    delimiter = *userInput.c_str();
}
```

When `userInput = \n`:

`userInput == "\n"` is false and `delimiter = \`

I need the delimiter to be the `\n` escape sequence, or any escape sequence, when the user chooses so.

Comment: Do you mean you want to read the character `'\'` followed by the character `'n'`, or you want to read a newline character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash here:

```
   if(userInput == "\n")
```

should be:

```
   if(userInput == "\\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is space-delimited, including `\n`, so you'll never get it from `operator>>`. You can check if `userInput` is an empty string and treat it as newline delimiter

Comment: He will get it if he enters the literal characters \ and n.

Comment: @NeilButterworth yep, I assumed just pressing `enter` is the simplest possible indication of newline delimiter